# How do I safely put an object in an __unsafe_unretained array?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nsdictionary

I am trying to process and change an NSDictionary's keys while keeping the same objects. The best approach seems to be using `-getObjects:andKeys:`s, modifying the array of keys, and then creating a new dictionary with `+dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:` to rebuild the dictionary. However, the arrays of objects and keys are `id __unsafe_unretained []`. Is there a way for me to safely assign the new key objects into that array, or do I have to create another array that's `id __strong []`?

The following example crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the last line:

```
NSDictionary *old = @{@"key1": @"foo", @"key2": @"bar"};

id __unsafe_unretained keys[2];
id __unsafe_unretained vals[2];
[old getObjects:vals andKeys:keys];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    keys[i] = [keys[i] uppercaseString];
}

NSDictionary *new = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:vals forKeys:keys count:2];

NSLog(@"New dict: %@", new);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right (and my first answer was wrong). Assigning a new value to `keys[i]`
does not retain the object, so you should create a new array for the keys:

```
NSDictionary *old = @{@"key1": @"foo", @"key2": @"bar"};

id __unsafe_unretained keys[2];
id newKeys[2];
id __unsafe_unretained vals[2];
[old getObjects:vals andKeys:keys];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    newKeys[i] = [keys[i] uppercaseString];
}

NSDictionary *new = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:vals forKeys:newKeys count:2];
```

Alternatively you could enumerate the old dictionary and create the new one
successively:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[old enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    key = [key uppercaseString];
    newDict[key] = obj;
}];
```

*(Old wrong answer deleted)*

Comment: Yes, but couldn't they be deallocated between the assignment and the call to `-dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:`?

Comment: @jtbandes: No, because the old dictionary also holds strong references.

Comment: To the old keys, yes — but not to any new objects which I've assigned into the `keys` array.

Comment: @jtbandes: You are right, my bad. Updated answer with alternative suggestion.

Comment: As a hypothetical reader of the code, I like the `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` option a lot better.